# Переход по введенной ссылке

Tags: java, android

Как в android при нажатии кнопки получить ссылку их EditText и затем открыть ее в браузере?

Comment: улыбок вам дед макар!

Answer (score 0):

Либо `WebView`, либо открывать сам браузер

```java
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Если вам нужен именно переход по ссылке, то это делается так:**

1. При нажатии на кнопку `button`, в конструкции `setOnClickListener()` достаем из `EditText` ссылку: **`String URL = get_url.getText().toString();`**
2. С помощью намерения (`intent`) открываем полученную ссылку в браузере:

   **`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));`**
   **`startActivity(browserIntent);`**

---

### Полный код:

```
package com.developer.appname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText get_url;
    Button open_url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        get_url = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        open_url = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        open_url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    String URL = get_url.getText().toString();
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Хотя это проще было просто нагуглить. Если вам нужен, как вы выражаетесь, браузер, то здесь вам на вряд ли кто-то объяснит. Про это надо читать :)

Comment: намертво завис эмулятор не знаю может с моим кодом что не то

Comment: Я отправил вам просто пример кода, чтобы показать, что должно располагаться в методе `onCreate()`. Вам нужно скопировать только определенные фрагменты и подставить их в обработку нажатия вашей кнопки.

Comment: @Lavrus, специально для вас докинул полный код для активити. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, самостоятельно :)